# display url with different value from what you put in search box ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a search box on admin page `admin.hbs` like this:

```
{{input value=search class="wide input" placeholder="Inquiry ID or User Email"}}
<div class="medium info btn" {{action 'search' search}}><button {{bind-attr class="isLoading:loading"}} >Search</button></div>
```

In the `admin_controller.js`, the search action looks like this:

```
search: function(search){
    if (!this.get('isLoading')){
        this.set('isLoading', true);
        if(search.indexOf('@') == -1){
            this.transitionToRoute('inquiry', search);
        } else {
            this.transitionToRoute('user', search);
        }
        this.set('isLoading', false);
      }
}
```

This function check whether the input is inquiry id or user email, and then transition to different route in order to get the right data. My issue is with the user search so I'll just show codes relates to user search. Here is the `router.js`:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("inquiry", {path: "inquiry/:inquiry_id"});
  this.route("user", {path: "user/:email"});
});
```

This is the `user_route.js`:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    email: {
        refresh: true,
    }
  },
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', {email: params.email}).then(function(users{
        if (users){
            return users.get('firstObject');
        }
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('isLoading', false);
  }
});
```

Currently the url is always like: `../admin/user/test1@gmail.com`
I want it to be like: `../admin/user/1`
I mean instead of showing the email I put in the search box, I want the url to show the user id, which is also a property in user model. I have a solution now: grab the user model in `admin_controller.js` depend on the user email. Then get the user id and pass the model to `user_route.js`. But I don't know how to get the user model in `admin_controller.js`. Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: It looks like you need [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize)

Comment: Yes I did try this way, but it didn't work. The url did not change. `serialize: function(model){
        return {email: model.id};
    },`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to perform your search in the `admin_controller.js`, but it could be done this way:

```
actions: {
  search: function(search) {
    if (!this.get('isLoading')){
      this.set('isLoading', true);
      this.performSearch(search, search.indexOf('@') == -1).then(function() {
        this.set('isLoading', false);
      });
    }
  }
},
// performSearch should be a normal method on the controller, not in the actions hash
performSearch: function(searchQuery, isUserSearch) {
  if(isUserSearch) {
    return this.store.find('user', {email: params.email}).then(function(users{
      if (users){
        const firstUser = users.get('firstObject');
        this.transitionToRoute('user', firstUser);
      }
    });
  } else {
    return ... // put your inquiry search code here, fetch the model and transition
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes sense. But how to get the model passed to route? I need to get it in user and inquiry route right?

Comment: If you pass a model (object) in `transitionToRoute` it should skip the `model` hook in the route it goes to (so for eg. the user route) and use the model you provided when calling `transitionToRoute`

Comment: Got you. Thanks so much!